# Complex number sine-cosine simplification: I can't understand this step.

Tags: complex-numbers

Good evening, I'm working on this step coming from a differential equation.
I have:

$A\cos(\frac{kL}{2})+Ai\sin(\frac{kL}{2})+B\cos(\frac{kL}{2})-Bi\sin(\frac{kL}{2})=0$

$(A+B)\cos(\frac{kL}{2})+(A-B)i\sin(\frac{kL}{2})=0$

This expression is set equal to:

$A\cos(\frac{kL}{2})+B\sin(\frac{kL}{2})=0$

$A$ and $B$ are constants (may be complex, not specified for this). $L$ is a real number. Obvioulsy this should be solved for variable $k$.

I can't explain which rules has been used to write down this step. Many thanks.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ real? How about $k$ - real? Integer? And $L$?

Comment: @Deepak: Even if they are, we can't deduce that $A\cos(\frac{kL}{2})+B\sin(\frac{kL}{2})=0$. It looks like somebody made a mistake here. To take a wild guess, perhaps $A+B$ and $A-B$ should be $A+iB$ and $A-iB$?

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that they are using $A,B$ etc for generic complex constants. The symbols in the two equations are not supposed to be the same constants.

Comment: @TonyK True. I'm just clarifying the question.

Comment: I've added some details to the question including the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$A\cos\left(\frac{kL}{2}\right)+Ai\sin\left(\frac{kL}{2}\right)=Ae^{i\frac{kL}{2}}$$
$$B\cos\left(\frac{kL}{2}\right)-Bi\sin\left(\frac{kL}{2}\right)=Be^{-i\frac{kL}{2}}$$
Looking at this I would assume that the step made was redefining one of the constants, since we cannot get from this line to the one stated

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. So I should have $Ae^{i\frac{kL}{2}}+Be^{-i\frac{kL}{2}}=0$. I still have troubles to understand if the result given by my book is correct or not. If it can help, this comes by the quantum physics "Particle in a Box" demonstration, but I posted here because I think is a math issue.